# Discord Server Joiner With Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code I made by myself. It's saying it joined, but it didn't. I need some help someone.

```
import requests

code = "y7EmKSE8ZX"

def join(file_path):
    while True:
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                token = line.strip()
                headers = {
                    'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
                url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{code}"
                
                try:
                    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={}, verify=False)
                    print(f"Joined, I think")
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    print(f"Error joining: {e}")

join("tokens.txt")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). From what I know, just opening an invite link doesn't add our account into a Discord server unless we click on Accept Invite or Join Group button. You don't just need to open the invite, you also need to click on join now. 
Either find a direct link that works or use a web driver module such as Selenium to move ahead on clicking that Join button.

Comment: Don't put this as discord.py because it does not use the discord.py library. You are just using requests.

Answer (score 0):

However, there are a few issues with the code that need to be addressed

In the context of Discord API authentication, the "Bearer" prefix is typically used for user access tokens, not bot tokens. Bot tokens are typically prefixed with "Bot" to indicate that they are used for bot accounts.

```
 headers = {
            'Authorization': f"Bot {token}",  # Add 'Bot ' prefix for bot tokens
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
```

Your code is using a **while True** loop, which means it will keep trying to join the server indefinitely. It's essential to have some stopping condition, or you may run into problems.

Use proper error handling and status code checking to determine success or failure when joining the server.

```
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={}, verify=False)
            if response.status_code == 204:
                print(f"Successfully joined with token: {token}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to join with token: {token}, Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error joining with token {token}: {e}")
```

Comment: I need to join with accounts, not bots!

Comment: If you want to join a server with a user account, it should be done manually through the Discord client. Discord does not provide a public API for programmatically joining servers with user accounts.

Comment: @RamziyaNisham In fact, it does. It requires the OAuth2 scope guilds.join. I'm not sure how to use it exactly since I've never needed to do it before but I know that it is possible once you have a web server and an app in the discord developer portal.

Comment: @chronosirius Thank you for pointing out the OAuth2 scope guilds.join. You are correct; it allows you to programmatically join a server using user accounts with the appropriate permissions and setup

Comment: However, this is against discord TOS to automate user accounts